# Spring cloud stream kafka stream binder - @Transactional annotation in functional programming model

Tags: transactions, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, kafka-streams-binder

I'm not able to perform database transaction rollback if exception occurs during event processing. I'm using spring cloud stream and kafka stream binder - together with functional programming model.

I retrieve event from topic, then put something into db if record is not registered there, and then produce new kafka message if some conditions are met. If something goes wrong I wanted to rollback db transaction - as well prevent from producing record.

pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I have method in PurchaseEventsProcessor

```
@Transactional
public Function<KStream<Long, Event>, KStream<Long, Event>> processPurchase() {

    return inputStream -> inputStream
            .filter(this::isValidPurchaseEvent)
            .filter((unused, event) -> Arrays.asList(allowedCountries).contains(event.country().name()))
            .mapValues(event -> customerHistoryService.registerPurchase(
                    event.timestamp(),
                    event.country(),
                    event.customerId(),
                    event.uuid(),
                    new BigDecimal(event.payload().get(REVENUE)))
            )
            .filter((unused, customerHistoryOptional) -> customerHistoryOptional.isPresent())
            .mapValues(customerHistoryOptional -> eventCreator.createRevenueIncreaseEvent(customerHistoryOptional.get()))
}
```

and in @Configuration I've added

```
@Bean
public Function<KStream<Long, Event>, KStream<Long, Event>> processPurchase() {
    return purchaseEventsProcessor.processPurchase();
}
```

If some exception is thrown during eventCreator.createRevenueIncreaseEvent then no new message is produced - but database record does not rollback. Is it even possible that @Transactional annotation works in this approach? Or is it executed only once during creation and proxy is never called later on.

Also if for example some exception occurs during processing message the transaction wont roll back.

Answer (score 0):

Using `@Transactional` as you described on a Kafka Streams function is not supported. As you correctly said, the method is called only once during creation, and the rest is delegated to Kafka Streams directly. You can however, extract the code that interacts with the database into a separate method and then mark it with `@Transactional` and then provide a database transaction manager such as the JPA one. When this isolated transactional method throws an exception, the database transaction is rolled back and the exception propagates to the Kafka Streams processor. This [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2023/10/16/apache-kafkas-exactly-once-semantics-in-spring-cloud-stream-kafka/#kafka-streams-and-exactly-once-semantics) has some more details about this specific use case.